# Spring cloud stream kafka stream Multiple Input Bindings no outputs

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple kafka stream app that process input from 3 topics but no out is required since the final step is to save the processing outcome to db.

I saw [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_beyond_two_inputs) for multiple inputs topics and that exactly what I need apart from the output binding, That is the bean should not return an output but should consume from 3 different topics as KStream,KTable and GlobalKtable and finish.
Any ideas how I can change the example for my needs?

Comment: Just make it a `Consumer` instead of a `Function`. Function has input/output bindings. Consumer has only input binding and Supplier has only output binding.

Comment: Thank you. But How to consume from 3 different topics only? one as KStream, other KTable and the third GlobalKTable.

Comment: Something like this: `public Function<KStream<Long, Order>,
        Function<GlobalKTable<Long, Customer>,
                Consumer<GlobalKTable<Long, Product>>>> enrichOrder()`